# Having issue with Laravel 5 in Codio

Tags: laravel, nginx, laravel-5, codio

Am trying to install Laravel 5 using Nginx on the cloud based IDE Codio following this tutorial ["Laravel, Codio, and Nginx "](http://jonathan.garbee.me/2014/04/laravel-codio-and-nginx.html)

After  setting everything, the browser show the content of the `puplic/index.php`  and not the default Laravel welcome page.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't sound like PHP-FPM is running. Check your nginx virtual host and see if there's a PHP directive. There should be plenty of tutorials out there to help you configure Nginx and PHP-FPM.

Comment: And were the `nginx virtual host `  is located?

Comment: It should be in /etc/nginx/sites-available/, if there is a virtual host there, could you post a hastebin of it?

Comment: I don't have that in Codio (or I can't find it).

Answer (score 0):

In terminal in Codio, run `parts status` to see what parts you have running and `parts list` to see what parts you have installed.

Also, check out the current [Laravel Starter Pack](https://codio.com/home/starter_packs/68232833-e7cb-4ec4-85ad-c5e3cb257162) in Codio. It is using 4.2 but will show you how it should be working and comparing what parts you have installed and running to what is in the starter pack should show you wnat you have missed

Comment: This is what I get with `parts status`:  `nginx    RUNNING, mariadb  RUNNING, php5-fpm RUNNING, mysql    STOPPED`. And  `parts list` shows this: `nginx (1.7.8)
mariadb (5.5.36)
libmcrypt (2.5.8) 
php5 (5.5.15) 
php5-fpm (5.5.15)
php5-curl (5.5.15)
mysql (5.6.15)
php5-pdo-mysql (5.5.15)
composer (1.0.0-20141216) ` I know About the Laravel Starter Pack but I want use Laravel 5 with Nginx (and not 4.2 with Apache)